# MRTKv2 'Interactable' script for dynamically added gameobjects

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

So I want to be able to use the 'Interactable' script in MRTKv2 for some of my gameobjects. I've had success when attaching the 'Interactable' and 'NearInteractionTouchable' script to the corresponding gameobject, but not when attempting to add the same functionality dynamically in the script.

Since the 'Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI' isn't currently defined, I know I can't reference the 'Interactable' script in the script directly, but in using the 'IMixedRealityFocusHandler', 'IMixedRealityPointerHandler', 'IMixedRealityTouchHandler', and 'IMixedRealityInputHandler' interfaces instead I still haven't had success in receiving any input.

[The namespaces currently defined by MRTKv2](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/Contributing/CodingGuidelines.html)

[All of the namespaces in MRTKv2](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/api/Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI.html)

[Event mapping from HL1 to HL2](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/HTKToMRTKPortingGuide.html)

Any ideas on a step that I'm missing to recreate the functionality of the 'Interactable' script that can be attached to gameobjects dynamically?

Comment: What you mean is that when you dynamically add an Interactable component to a gameobject, you can't call the function of Interactable component in another script component?

Comment: Could you show your code please and explain where exactly the issue is?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want to use 'Interactable' dynamicly, and it is not possible with current version of MTRK. And you are tring to create your own "interactable' method. If I'm right, why you just dont use the older version of MTRK?

Answer (score 1):

Interactable does exist in the MRTK namespace under using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI; perhaps you are missing references to your projects? The following code works for me, using the latest mrtk_development:

```cs
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI;
using UnityEngine;

public class AddInteractableTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        gameObject.AddComponent<Interactable>();
        gameObject.AddComponent<NearInteractionTouchable>();
    }
}
```